# Bootstrap navbar showing border after modal popup have been hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap in my Rails app, in it I have a navbar that contains some elements. When I press one of these elements I present a modal popup. When I close this popup, the clicked element for some reason gets highlighted. This isn't the experience I'm looking for.

See image below:

[image]

I wonder how I can get rid of this unwanted effect?

Comment: Your picture does not illustrate your problem. Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle / bootply? Is it just an issue of "focus"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without you supplying us with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it is very hard for us to determine what is going on exactly.

Although, from your image, it seems as if it is just 'focus'. Below is an image from the Bootstrap website, and it features one of their 'default' buttons. On the left is the button in its original state, and on the right is the button after I have clicked on it and it is in 'focus'. Chrome, by default (created by their 'user agent stylesheet') places this light blue border around elements once they are focused.

[image]

To remove the border for all fields you can use the following:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

To remove the border for selected fields just apply this class to the input fields you want:

```
.nohighlight:focus {
     outline:none;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem, may I know how you solved that? The above solution does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @fyr0049, try outline:none!important

Comment: Im using <a> tag and it didn't for me, even with !important

Answer (score 0):

```
*:focus  
{  
    outline: none;  
}
```

this is work like a charm